# Frequency Transform : Fundametal Concept

Tags: signal-processing

I was going thru this book to understand wavelets. Its a beautifully written not much technical document.

web.iitd.ac.in/~sumeet/WaveletTutorial.pdf

But in its very first chapter it describes below figure with explanation:

> The frequency is measured in cycles/second, or with a more common
>   name, in "Hertz". For example the electric power we use in our daily
>   life in the US is 60 Hz (50 Hz elsewhere in the world). This means
>   that if you try to plot the electric current, it will be a sine wave
>   passing through the same point 50 times in 1 second. Now, look at the
>   following figures. The first one is a sine wave at 3 Hz, the second
>   one at 10 Hz, and the third one at 50 Hz. Compare them

[image: Frequency]

But I am unable to understand what X and Y axis values represents. The X values range is in between [1,-1] so I am assuming it is value of the signal while Y axis is representing the time in milliseconds (1000ms = 1 sec). But then the document goes on further to state the representation of same signal in frequency-amplitude domain:

> So how do we measure frequency, or how do we find the frequency
>   content of a signal? The answer is FOURIER TRANSFORM (FT). If the FT
>   of a signal in time domain is taken, the frequency-amplitude
>   representation of that signal is obtained. In other words, we now have
>   a plot with one axis being the frequency and the other being the
>   amplitude. This plot tells us how much of each frequency exists in our
>   signal.

[image: Frequency]

But I am not able to understand what does in the upper graph X and Y axis values represents - shouldn't is be Frequency (X Axis) and Amplitude (Y axis) - if I am correct then why does Y axis has values ranked as **0,200 and 400** - shouldn't it be between range [1,-1] or rather [0,1]?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic signal processing theory and so belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time domain signals the X axis is time and the Y axis is amplitude.

For the frequency domain equivalents the X axis is frequency and the Y axis is magnitude.

Note that when using most FFTs there is a scaling factor of N, where N is the number of points, so the magnitude values in the frequency domain plots are much greater than amplitude of the original time domain signal.

Comment: Then how come time values be in between -1 and 1? It should be a value that should increase positive side constantly.

Comment: I think maybe you're getting confused between X and Y axes (Y is the vertical axis, X is the horizontal axis) ? Also see my edit above.

Comment: Correct so how the second figure states amplitude as range 0,200 and 400 where in first graph it is represented as Y axis in range -1,1

Comment: Time domain *amplitudes* can be positive or negative (think of each an AC voltage signal). Frequency domain *magnitudes* are the magnitude of a complex FFT output bin, so they are always positive. See also my edit regarding FFT scaling factors.

Comment: Thanks I got your point so I can image the second figure having Y axis values range between [0,1] values or [0,400] having a scaling factor of 400 - in case I am not wrong

Comment: My guess is that the FFT size is 1024, so you are seeing a scaling factor of 512 on the peaks in each half of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul R wrote above, in the first image the horizontal X-axis represents time with the units ms.
The time interval has the length 1000ms.

The vertical Y-axis represents the amplitude of the signal. However, in the diagram the unit is not Volt, but it is normalized to amplitude 1.

If you perform a Fourier Transformation on that time signal, you will get a frequency spectrum.
If you use a DFT (Discrete Fourier Transformation) or a FFT (Fast Fourier Transformation),
the result depends on the implementation of the algorithm.

a) If the algorithm delivers a normalized result, the amplitude of your frequency line is 0.5 (if the amplitude of your input signal is 1).

b) If the algorithm delivers a non normalized result, the amplitude of your frequency line is half the value of the number of DFT/FFT input values.

Your frequency line has the value of 500, which means the algorithm does not use normalization and the number of input samples was 1000.

Now, what is represented by the horizontal X-axes in the frequency domain?
In the time domain, the length of your time input interval is T = 1000ms = 1s.
Therefore the distance between the frequency lines in the frequency domain is df = 1/s = 1Hz.

As we know from the amplitude in the frequency domain, the input signal in time domain had 1000 samples. This means the sampling time was dt = T/1000 = 1s/1000 = 1ms.
Therefore the total frequency interval F = (fmin, ..., fmax) in frequency domain is 1/dt = 1/1ms = 1kHz.

However, the range does NOT start at fmin = 0 Hz and ends at 1kHz, as one could assume inspecting the upper diagram in the second image. The spectrum calculated by a DFT/FFT contains a positive and a negative frequency range. This means you get a frequency range: (-500Hz, -499Hz, -498Hz, ... -1Hz, 0Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz, ..., 498Hz, 499Hz). The value 500Hz does not exist!

However, for the user's convenience the spectrum is not output in this order, but it is shifted by 500Hz (F/2). This means the spectrum starts with the DC value:
0Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz, ..., 498Hz, 499Hz, -500Hz, -499Hz, -498Hz, ..., -2Hz, -1HZ.

Because the spectrum of a real input function is hermitian Y(f) == Y(-f)*, the positive band carries the complete information. So, you can cut off the negative side band.

The upper diagram in the second image shows two peaks. The first peak appears at f = 50Hz and the second peak is shown at f=950Hz. However, this is not correct. The labels of the horizontal axes are wrong. The second peak appears at f = -50Hz.

In the lower diagram the frequency range ends at 500Hz (499Hz would be correct)a). The range of the negative frequencies is cut off.